# Railstutorial.org Ruby on Rails Routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm following along to Michael Hartl's Screencasts from railstutorial.org.  I only have a tiny bit of PHP, html, and css experience under my belt, and I'm okay with bash commands, but object oriented languages are completely new to me.

Here's the problem:  I have an app called sample_app.  From the command line:

```
 .../sample_app$ rails generate controller Pages home contact
```

Now, when I look at routes.rb:

```
 SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

    get "pages/home"

    get "pages/contact"
```

And when I look at pages_controller I see:

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController

      def home
      end

      def contact
      end
end
```

When I attempt to go to "localhost:3000/pages/home" I get the following error page:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches "/pages/home"

I have a suspicion there is something else going on here, because I create a static html file in the folder Public, and could not get it to load either:

Here's my static page in Public:

```
<html>
<h1> TACO!</h1>
    <body>
        <p> testing <p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And when I attempt to navigate to "localhost:3000/taco.html" I get the same type of error:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches "/taco.html"

- EDIT:  By the way localhost:3000 by itself does load the index.html "welcome to rails blah" page just fine..

You'd be surprised how long I have been attempting to figure this out.  I have a feeling this is either a super simple fix, or something is terribly wrong.  One or the other...

Just so you know:
Rails 3.0.3
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
gems 1.4.2

Any ideas?  This very well might be a RTFM kind of deal, if so just tell me, and I will look harder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I'm a dummy.  rails was still running a server in the background from my old app...

And I think I know how it happened without me knowing it too.   When I started the server for the other app, I think I remember doing:

```
rails s &
```

So that I could keep using the terminal window.  But that causes the problem of not being able to easily shut the server back down with Ctrl C.

So I did `lsof -i :3000`

which outputed:

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby1.8 20667 kevin    5u  IPv4 7193288      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

so then i killed it with:

```
kill -9 20667
```

With a little help from google of course...  Sweet!  Thanks for the help, knowing that it worked on someone else's end and not mine was a good start and I did learn a lot of other things by sifting through that documentation anyway...

Comment: also, i had no idea that rails pretty much logs everything in that terminal window, which I imagine will be very useful for me later

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your app so far and it works fine, i would suggest you check your installation of Rails and gem files.

EDIT. I am using rails 3 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the tutorial you're using is a Rails 2 tutorial. In Rails 3 the routing language changed. What you want looks like this.

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match "/home" => "pages#home"
  match "/contact" => "pages#contact"
end
```

Then you will create "app/views/pages/home.html.erb" and "app/views/pages/contact.html.erb". Whatever you put in these two html files will be served when you go to /home or /contact. Variables are defined in the controller file app/controllers/pages.rb. If you define:

```
def contact
  @contact = 'John Smith'
end
```

Then you can access this in "app/views/pages/contact.html.erb" like so.

```
<h1>Contact name: <%= @contact %></h1>
```

Comment: Interesting.  In the tutorial screencasts, Michael is using Rails 3.0.0 release candidate, so maybe it was still using the older routing language at that time.   Although I'm confused:  Why would my version (rails 3.0.3 create the old routing language for me, when I did "rails generate controller Pages home contact" ?

Comment: I hope I'm not a nuisance, but would it help if I showed you my gem list, or anything else?  Once I'm on the right track here, I'll be able to self-teach a little more, but this is straight wild west for me right now...

Comment: get and post is perfectly fine to use if you want to be explicit about the request type. And you don't need the value (=> "xxx") if it's specified in the get/post, p.ex. get "/pages/home".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your answer, I had the same issue occur. I don't know what all of that lsof and kill is but I closed the terminal with the server running then reran the `$ rails generate controller Pages home contact` and then ran `$ rails server` and after that my localhost:3000/pages/home worked as shown on page 81.